# How to write custom routes for python eve-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, eve

Based on the tutorials of '[EVE-SQLAlchemy](https://eve-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io)' I am able to setup a fully functional REST API which can setup a database based on a schema definition which used SQL alchemys database Models to generate the REST API schema. I am able to do CRUD operations on the resources. It's all good!

Now, how do I add custom routes which can run queries or manipulate the database etc. Say I want to add additional functionalities and it is not straighforward resource queries and involves multiple SQL actions. How to achieve that?

Sorry for not being very specific. Any general idea in that direction will be appreciated like some sort of guide or tutorial which can help understand the eve framework better. I want to stick to EVE's features while I add additional routes to it. Don't want to re-invent everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using flask's blueprints. This [example](http://python-eve.org/snippets/hooks_blueprints.html) from eve's documentation shows how to use event hooks inside blueprints, but you can see on it how you create a blueprint and do whatever you want inside it, like your queries.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try it for my requirement and let you know. Got a lot of reading to do. :)